# Combine multiple mysql queries into one

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have multiple mysql queries being executed in PHP and wondering if the performance would improve if they were all put into one query? If so how ?

The plan is to find all records with `submitstatus = 1` in the 3 tables and get the manager value from the USER_TABLE.

```
    $results = $pdo->query("SELECT DISTINCT (u.manager)
        FROM $USER_TABLE u
        LEFT JOIN $ONCALL_TABLE o ON o.uid = u.username
        WHERE o.submitstatus = 1");
    foreach($results as $data) {
        $manager[] = $data['manager'];
    }

    $results = $pdo->query("SELECT DISTINCT (u.manager)
        FROM $USER_TABLE u
        LEFT JOIN $TIMEOFF_TABLE t ON t.uid = u.username
        WHERE t.submitstatus = 1");
    foreach($results as $data) {
        $manager[] = $data['manager'];
    }

    $results = $pdo->query("SELECT DISTINCT (u.manager)
        FROM $USER_TABLE u
        LEFT JOIN $SHIFTPREMIUM_TABLE s ON s.uid = u.username
        WHERE s.submitstatus = 1");
    foreach($results as $data) {
        $manager[] = $data['manager'];
    }
```

I tried the query below but the speed slowed down and was not as good as the 3 separate queries.

```
$results = $pdo->query("SELECT 
                         DISTINCT(manager)
                          FROM $USER_TABLE 
                          WHERE 
 username IN (SELECT $ONCALL_TABLE.uid FROM $ONCALL_TABLE WHERE $ONCALL_TABLE.submitstatus=1) OR 
 username IN (SELECT $TIMEOFF_TABLE.uid FROM $TIMEOFF_TABLE WHERE $TIMEOFF_TABLE.submitstatus=1) OR 
 username IN (SELECT $SHIFTPREMIUM_TABLE.uid FROM $SHIFTPREMIUM_TABLE WHERE $SHIFTPREMIUM_TABLE.submitstatus=1)");
```

Comment: `IN (<subquery>)` tends to be slow. `OR` tends to be slow. You have both in your new query.

Comment: ??? All your 3 queries are by fact `SELECT DISTINCT manager FROM $USER_TABLE`. Or even `SELECT manager FROM $USER_TABLE` if `manager` column is unique. Their combining can add nothing.

Comment: Please take some time to look at the MANY other posts here on query optimization. Note which are voted up/ansered and which are voted down/closed. As a minimum you should include EXPLAIN plans and schema details. Providing an indication of the data distribution for the predicates is also helpful.

Comment: Continuing from Akina's point, given your description of what you are trying to achive, those should be INNER joins, not LEFT joins.

Comment: @symcbean I'm wondering whats the best approach to put the 3 queries into one for better performance. The plan is to find all records with submitstatus = 1 in the 3 tables and get the manager value from the USER_TABLE.

Comment: `UNION` is your friend here

Comment: And where does this come from: `OR $TIMEOFF_TABLE.cancel=1`? It wasn't in your first queries.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel That shouldn't have been there.. I've made the edit.  Are you able to provide a quick example with UNION ?

Comment: @rubberchicken: please read all the comments again carefully. Restating what you said in your original question is not helpful.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel You're right about UNION, I put them all into one query and seems to be working great. Thanks !

Comment: Sounds like the 3 tables need to be combined into one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since all three results are *compatible* (same columns and types), and even select the same column from the same table, and then are merged into one array anyway - You can use `UNION` to "combine" the results.

```
$results = $pdo->query("
    SELECT DISTINCT (u.manager) FROM $USER_TABLE u 
    JOIN $ONCALL_TABLE o ON o.uid = u.username 
    WHERE o.submitstatus = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT DISTINCT (u.manager) 
    FROM $USER_TABLE u 
    JOIN $TIMEOFF_TABLE t ON t.uid = u.username 
    WHERE t.submitstatus = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT DISTINCT (u.manager) 
    FROM $USER_TABLE u 
    JOIN $SHIFTPREMIUM_TABLE s ON s.uid = u.username 
    WHERE s.submitstatus = 1
");
foreach($results as $data) {
    $manager[] = $data['manager'];
}
```

The above code is equivalet to your three queries. Note that I removed the `LEFT` keywords, since all your LEFT joins will be converted to INNER joins anyway.

If duplicates are possible, you can also use `UNION DISTINCT` or just `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL` (`DISTINCT` is default).

A slightly other way would be to first find all *usernames* (of interest) in a UNION subquery, and use a single join on the users table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.manager
FROM (
    SELECT o.uid FROM $ONCALL_TABLE o       WHERE o.submitstatus = 1
    UNION
    SELECT t.uid FROM $TIMEOFF_TABLE t      WHERE t.submitstatus = 1
    UNION
    SELECT s.uid FROM $SHIFTPREMIUM_TABLE s WHERE s.submitstatus = 1
) sub
JOIN $USER_TABLE u on u.username = sub.uid
```

Note that I do not know your data distribution, so it's on you you to figure out where you need `DISTINCT` and where you don't. Avoiding `DISTINCT` can improve the performance.

Comment: The modified query you last posted is the best for performance (at least for me) and cleanest.  Appreciate your time and great explanation on this! Thanks